# Storing articles with separate chapters

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of building a simple blog-ish website, and I'm unsure about how to structure storage of articles/blogs in a database. I have a very simple editor, which separates input into individual chapters before submitting them, like (retrieved from php print_r):

```
Array
(
    [entry_title] => ENTRY_TITLE
    [chapter_header] => Array
    (
        [0] => CHAPTER_1
        [1] => CHAPTER_2
    )

    [chapter_content] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lorem Ipsum...
        [1] => Lorem Ipsum...
    )
)
```

Should I create a new table for storing chapters individually, or concatenate all chapters into one long string and store as a single TEXT field?

Imagined database structure would be something like:

```
TABLE posts:
id
title
chapters (references unique table with chapters for this specific entry)

TABLE chapters (unique identifier per post):
chapter_header
chapter_content
```

vs. this, storing article as one long string

```
TABLE posts:
id
title
content (with html tags to separate titles and chapters)
```

I imagine the first structure will make it easier to identify unique chapters, for styling purposes (without having to parse the input to add unique identifiers in the form of HTML classes or IDs). However, I'm not sure if creating a new table for each entry is "correct procedure" or considered bad practice.

Comment: Definitely store chapters in their own table. MySQL is a RDBMS, the R stands for *relational*. Read about data normalization, it will help.

Comment: @AymDev Thank you. Would you recommend storing the chapters for each entry in their own table, or have a shared table for storing all chapters (post id, chapter header, chapter content)?

Comment: Think about it: would you create a table each time you want to create a chapter ? Tables with a single line and the same structure ? Or would you have a single table where you insert a line per chapter ? Read about data normalization and how to create relations using foreign key constraints. Once you get it you'll be able to modelize the database for most of your projects. The answer is a single table, btw.